# Assigning point attribute to overlapping polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-processing, overlapping-features, point-in-polygon

Are there a way to assign the attributes of a point to a overlapping polygon?

I got the data as lines and points. The lines are making the polygons and the points are overlapping the created polygon with the data stored the the point, but I need polygons with the same data as in the points for my analysis.

Comment: Please search for **qgis spatial join**. You will find sufficient posts and tutorials. For example: [Performing Spatial Joins](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_joins.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

- [Join attributes by location](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgisjoinattributesbylocation)

> Takes an input vector layer and creates a new vector layer that is an
> extended version of the input one, with additional attributes in its
> attribute table.Takes an input vector layer and creates a new vector
> layer that is an extended version of the input one, with additional
> attributes in its attribute table.

Answer (score 5):

1. To create polygon from the lines, use [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) with this expression:

   ```
   make_polygon($geometry)
   ```
2. To get the attribute value of overlapping points, use field calculator with this expression:

   ```
   overlay_contains('points', value)[0]
   ```

*Inputs are red points and red line; blue polygons created with step 1. Polygons are labeled with the expression from step 2:*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [virtual layer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/de/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) to create the result at once, avoiding the two step approach in the other solution.

Use this query, where `polygon` is the name of your polygon layer,  `point` the name of the point-layer and `poly_id` / `pt_id` the names of the respective unique id in the two layers:

```
select pol.poly_id, poi.pt_id , pol.geometry
from polygon as pol join point as poi on st_within(poi.geometry, pol.geometry)
```

*Red dots and red outline: initial layers (point, polygon); dark yellow: virtual layer with the id of the point within each polygon as label:*
[image]